# Can I declare two variables inside of if scope in go?

Tags: go, if-statement, syntax

I started to learn go. Now, I have started "if" part.

In go, I knew that is possible to declare variable on if scope. Like this...

```
if koreanAge := age + 2; koreanAge < 18 {
    return false
}
```

At this point, I wondered that **is possible to declare two variables in if scope**. Like this...

```
if koreanAge := age + 2, japanAge := age + 1; koreanAge < 18 {
    return false
}
```

In my country, South Korea, go is not popular than other language.. And I have bad english skills.
I can't find information related to this...

If I try to run compiler, This error is shown.

```
$ go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:11:36: syntax error: unexpected :=, expecting {
```

Please, need your help.
Thanks for read this.

Comment: It's `if koreanAge, japanAge := age + 2, age + 1; ... {`.

Comment: Note that the proper syntax for initializing multiple variables is, as shown above, `identifier_list := expression_list`, it is *not* `identifier1 := expression1, identifier2 := expression2 ...`. The latter is invalid syntax, regardless of whether it's within the `if` statement or not. See: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

Comment: @mkopriva It works!! Thank you for your kindness! The second syntax's reason is that I used CSharp, then inadvertently mixed it up and thought about it...

Answer (score 1):

First, declare variables names divided by comma and, after that, initialize them as [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) suggested you. Here is an example on the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/x8lrXAe6UTK).